# Drag and Drop button tkinter python

Tags: python, button, tkinter, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm new using tkinter on python and I would like to develop a program that can Drag and Drop a button pressing other one... I will try to explain : I have button 'A' that will create a new button 'B'  and I want to Drag the New button to another place
Any help
Thanks

Comment: Interesting concept. I am not sure you can create a floating button that you can drag.

Comment: There are questions on this site related to dragging and dropping objects. Did you do any research before asking?

Comment: I checked but did ni found the answer any help?

Comment: I suggest you to check the `tkinter.dnd` [module](https://github.com/akheron/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/dnd.py) (dnd stands for drag and drop)

Comment: Thanks Any help will be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`tkinter.dnd`](https://github.com/akheron/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/dnd.py) module, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803301/drag-and-drop-button-tkinter-python#comment88615794_50803301) by [j_4321](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6415268/j-4321) in comments.
Here is some sample code using that library to do what you have said:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.dnd import Tester as DragWindow, Icon as Dragable

# Make a root window and hide it, since we don't need it.
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
# Make the actual main window, which can have dragable objects on.
main = DragWindow(root)

def make_btn():
    """Make a new test button."""
    # The functional part of the main window is the canvas.
    Dragable('B').attach(main.canvas)

# Make a button and bind it to our button creating function.
Button(main.top, text='A', command=make_btn).pack()
# Start the mainloop.
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help that actually I wanted you save my live you are a hero without cap

Comment: Would there be a way to do this with buttons that you can also press to run a command? E.X the files on windows desktop can be dragged but also double-clicked to open them.

Comment: @CodeWizard777 Not using `tkinter.dnd.Icon`, as far as I can tell, but that's only meant for demonstration purposes anyway. See [the source code](https://github.com/akheron/cpython/blob/f91d2f2e2e992c3006a5023eb4ba3cf0d082fde8/Lib/tkinter/dnd.py#L208) for an idea of how to implement your own dragable widget