# Tkinter buttons getting hidden behind other frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a battlemap for dnd ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDaA7.jpg)) with adjustable grid and movable enemy/creature tokens. The idea is to drag one of the token from the right onto the map on the left.

The window is made of 3 frames. The frame for the map, the frame for the "new map" button and slider. And then frame for the tokens, which are buttons tiled using button.grid()

I found a drag and drop system [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887576/how-can-i-create-a-drag-and-drop-interface) that I'm using to drag the tokens. However, when I bring them over the map, they go behind it and you can't see them (I know they go behind because they can be partially visible between the two frames). Is there any way to bring them to the front?

```
import tkinter as tk

class DragManager():
    def add_dragable(self, widget):
        widget.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_start)
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_drag)
        widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_drop)
        widget.configure(cursor="hand1")

    def on_start(self, event):
        # you could use this method to create a floating window
        # that represents what is being dragged.
        pass

    def on_drag(self, event):
        # you could use this method to move a floating window that
        # represents what you're dragging
        event.widget.place(x=event.x_root + event.x, y= event.y_root + event.y)

    #when button is dropped, create a new one where this one originally was
    def on_drop(self, event):
        # find the widget under the cursor
        x,y = event.widget.winfo_pointerxy()
        target = event.widget.winfo_containing(x,y)
        try:
            target.configure(image=event.widget.cget("image"))
        except:
            pass
        if x > window.winfo_screenwidth() - 200:
            del event.widget
            return
        if not event.widget.pure:
            return
        button = tk.Button(master=entity_select_frame, text = "dragable", borderwidth=1, compound="top")
        #avoiding garbage collection
        button.gridx = event.widget.gridx
        button.gridy = event.widget.gridy
        button.grid(row = event.widget.gridx, column = event.widget.gridy)
        button.grid()
        button.pure = True
        dnd.add_dragable(button)

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1000x800")
map_frame = tk.Frame()
controls_frame = tk.Frame(width=200, borderwidth=1, relief=tk.RAISED)
tk.Label(master=controls_frame, text="controls here").pack()
entity_select_frame = tk.Frame(width=200, relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)

dnd = DragManager()
button = tk.Button(master=entity_select_frame, text = "dragable", borderwidth=1)
button.gridx = 0
button.gridy = 0
button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
button.pure = True
dnd.add_dragable(button)


map_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
controls_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
entity_select_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Art Updated the post

Comment: Check out this post about [tkinter drag and drop functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803301/drag-and-drop-button-tkinter-python)

Answer (score 1):

I played around a little bit and used stuff from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280004/tkinter-how-to-drag-and-drop-widgets). I did not structure it as a class and I used the picture frame as my root-frame and put the control-frame inside that. I'm not sure how this would be best combined with your "draw-grid", "token" functionalities etc., however I hope it helps. I did not find a way to drag widgets across frames though (tried to set a new master for the button, recreate it after dropping it etc.). Get the image used in my code from [here](https://angelamaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Island_AngelaMaps-1024x768.jpg).

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, Canvas, font
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

""" ####################### Configuration parameters ###################### """
image_file_path = "Island_AngelaMaps-1024x768.jpg"
resize_img = False  # set to True if you want to resize the image > window size
resize_to = (600, 600)  # resolution to rescale image to


""" ####################### Drag and drop functionality ################### """


def make_draggable(widget):
    widget.bind("<Button-1>", on_drag_start)
    widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag_motion)


def on_drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget._drag_start_x = event.x
    widget._drag_start_y = event.y


def on_drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_start_x + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_start_y + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)


""" ################################# Layout ############################## """

# picture frame with picture as background
picture_frame = Frame(root)
picture_frame.pack(side="left", anchor="w", fill="both", expand=True)

# load the image
if resize_img:
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_file_path).resize(resize_to, Image.ANTIALIAS))
else:
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_file_path))

# create canvas, set canvas background to the image
canvas = Canvas(picture_frame, width=img.width(), height=img.height())
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.background = img  # Keep a reference in case this code is put in a function.
bg = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img)

# subframe inside picture frame for controls
ctrl_subframe = Frame(picture_frame)
ctrl_subframe.pack(side="right", anchor="n")

# separator between picture and controls, inside picture frame
ttk.Separator(picture_frame, orient="vertical").pack(side="right", fill="y")

# underlined label 'Controls' in subframe
ctrl_header = Label(ctrl_subframe, text="Controls", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
f = font.Font(ctrl_header, ctrl_header.cget("font"))
f.configure(underline=True)
ctrl_header.configure(font=f)
ctrl_header.pack(side="top", pady=2)

# update window to get proper sizes from widgets
root.update()

# a draggable button, placed below ctrl_header
# (based on X of ctrl_subframe and height of ctrl_header, plus padding)
drag_button = Button(picture_frame, text="Drag me", bg="green", width=6)
drag_button.place(x=ctrl_subframe.winfo_x()+2, y=ctrl_header.winfo_height()+10)
make_draggable(drag_button)


""" ################################ Mainloop ############################# """

root.mainloop()
```